# Pre-fetch api data in Vuex with Nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, prefetch

I am trying to pre-fetch some data and update Vuex before client-side kicks in.

`store/index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({});
export const getters = {};
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('nasa/getImages');
  }
};
```

`store/moduleName.js`

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export const state = () => ({
  images: []
});

export const mutations = {
  storeImages(state, data) {
    state.images = [];
    state.images.push(...data);
    console.log(state.images[0]); <- this logs in the terminal
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getImages(store) {
    return fetch('api/url').then(response => {
      response.json().then(function(data) {
          store.commit('storeImages', data.collection.items.slice(0, 24));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My mutation gets triggered by **nuxtServerInit** and I am getting the first element logged in the terminal on page load. My store in the client-side however, is empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand right - have you seen that one?: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/

Comment: @Soleno sorry for the late reply; I did take a look at that before, however, the example there shows how to trigger the action in the store by dispatching from client side rather than the server side (which is what I am after)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from a friend we have managed to fix this issue by removing **node-fetch** and adding **axios** to Vuex instead.

The only change made was in `store/moduleName.js` which now looks like:

```
import Axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
  images: []
});

export const mutations = {
  storeImages(state, data) {
    state.images.push(...data);
  }
}

export const actions = { 
  async getImages(store) {
    let res = await Axios.get('api/url');
    store.commit('storeImages', res.data.collection.items.slice(0, 24));
  } 
}
```